# Move down text in KOMA-Script header with picture

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

In my Document is a picture on the left side of the header (`\ihead`) and some text on the right side (`\ohead`). My problem is that the picture moves the text up from the `headsepline` and I have no idea how to move it down again.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
oneside
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{                      
    a4paper,
    left=25mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=20mm,
    foot=10mm,
    headsep=5mm,
    heightrounded,
    %showframe
}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=0.5pt}
\ihead{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{pics/hsb}}   % Kopfzeile links
\ohead{SAMPLE}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image: with picture in header]

The result without including the picture:

[image: without the picture]

How can i get the `SAMPLE` text back to the `headsepline`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default of `scrlayer-scrpage` is to vertically center the three header/footer boxes. So one suggestion would be to set the height of the image to the height of a standard text line using `\ht\strutbox` as (first) optional argument of a `\raisebox`:

```latex
\documentclass[
oneside% default and therefore not needed
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{                      
    a4paper,% default of scrreprt and therefore not needed
    left=25mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=20mm,
    foot=10mm,
    headsep=5mm,
    heightrounded,
    %showframe
}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=0.5pt}
\ihead{\raisebox{0pt}[\ht\strutbox]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}}   % Kopfzeile links
\ohead{SAMPLE}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Using `\smash` instead of `\raisebox{0pt}[\ht\strutbox]` would also work.

Both suggestions also remove the warning:

> `Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: \headheight to low.`

Comment: That worked perfectly! Is the warning coming from the definition of the margins?

Comment: The warning was, because the image is higher than `\headheight`. But my `\raisebox` reduces the logical height and `\smash` even sets it to 0.